# Creating knowledge graph index out of a XML (DEXPI) file

Tags: xml, graph-databases, large-language-model, llama-index, retrieval-augmented-generation

**Context:**

I have a XML file (DEXPI) and I want to use it as a data source to implement Retrieval Augmented Generation (RAG) system using `llama-index` to fetch the correct context against any natural language query.

**Current Issue:**

- I cannot use the XML file like a text document.
- `llama-index` does not provide any type of splitter for XML data so that XML data can be correctly divided into chunks (nodes).
- Even if we write some custom chunker/splitter, a lot of unwanted jargons would be still there in the chunks like XML tags and other metadata related to XML.

**What did I try?**

To solve this issue I have 2 approaches:

**Approach 1:**

Convert the XML into SQl tables (or CSVs). Convert these tables into natural language english text. Then pass this text to `llama-index` for further processing. Here, while preparing the knowledge graph index, the `llama-index` will automatically figure out the vertices (entities) and the edges (relationships) between them.

**Approach 2:**

Convert the XML into SQL tables (or CSVs). Convert these SQL tables into Graph DB entities & relationships manually. Then query the graph db by using a graph query generated from any LLM.

**My Questions:**

1. I need suggestions on which approach to choose currently & how effective they are.
2. Are there any better approaches to deal with **XML** data when using `llama-index`.

Comment: I would create a Powershell script to parse the xml into another format like CSV.  You can  also with Powershell connect to a SQL Server and store data into the database.